# Laravel get count on belongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

in my project i have two model as:

Contents:

```
class Contents extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contents';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContentCategories::class);
    }
}
```

and Categories:

```
class ContentCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contents_categories';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contents::class);
    }
}
```

in my project each content must be have one or more category and i want to get count of content that they are assigned to categories by this code:

```
$categories = ContentCategories::with('contents');
dd($categories->contents->count());
```

unfortunately i get this error:

```
"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$contents"
```

how can i resolve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$categories` variable is a collection in which each category has a `contents` attribute. So you can do `->contents->count()` on each category, but not on the entire collection.

If you want the count of each category, just do it inside a foreach loop when you need it.

If you want the total number of contents that have connections to categories, there's a better way:

```
Contents::has('categories')->count();
```

As an aside, I would suggest renaming your models to singular, since each instance is *one* of something, but that's just a suggestion.

Comment: At this point `$categories` is still a Builder since he didn't use `get()` method. But you'are correct.

Comment: @joel-hinz thanks, my problem resolved by your descriptions and this code: `$categories = ContentCategories::with('contents')->get();`

Comment: @cbaconnier Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use count for one category as follows:

```
$category = ContentCategories::find($id);
$category->contents()->count();
```

Beware the () after contents, to count in SQL level!

Why? In short,

```
$categories->contents
```

is the same with

```
$categories->contents()->get()
```